# Failed SELECT value from Date field (single value)

Tags: 7, entities, datetime

I've installed [date module](http://drupal.org/project/date). the field data stored in `field_data_field_date_start_rent`. The field dont have multiple values

I want to select `field_date_start_rent_value`.

So, I'm testing SELECT it and UPDATE to other date field. It not works.

Below is the SELECT, but I'm using text field to UPDATE to see if it works:

```
$nid = $node->nid;
$startrent = db_query("SELECT field_date_start_rent_value FROM {field_data_field_date_start_rent} WHERE entity_id = $nid")->fetchField();
$endrentf = db_query("UPDATE {field_data_field_cubagan} SET field_cubagan_value = $startrent WHERE entity_id = $nid");
return $endrentf;
```

If using the same SELECT query on integer field, it works without problem. I think it must have something different in the SELECT query for date field.

Comment: You should never use SQL queries to get, and update the value of a field implemented through the field API, for the simple fact field data are not always saved in a database table. It depends from the implemented [field storage API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/group/field_storage/7), and modules can implement a different field storage API that saves the data in a file, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a lot easier to use a different set of API calls to do this, you can avoid having to manipulate the database directly:

```
// Extract the first field item
$date_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_date_start_rent');
$date_item = array_shift($date_items);

// Get the field value
$start_rent = $date_item['value'];

// Update the other field
$node->field_cubagan[$node->language][0]['value'] = $start_rent;

// Save the node
node_save($node);
```

Just as an aside: you're not making the best use of the DB API at the moment, you should be using placeholders and provide arguments to `db_query()` rather than interpolating them directly into the query string. The equivalent of your `SELECT` statement written the recommended way would be:

```
$args = array(':nid' => $node->nid);
$sql = 'SELECT field_date_start_rent_value FROM {field_data_field_date_start_rent} WHERE entity_id = :nid';
$startrent = db_query($sql, $args)->fetchField();
```

Comment: In above example, Is `$node->language` mandatory even if the website don't have translation choice?

Comment: Yes, it will be `und` for `undetermined` if you don't have a multilingual site; but you still need it in there