# Unable calculate date field using strtotime

Tags: 7, entities, datetime

From [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/35597/6775), the result will be in text field `field_cubagan`.

Actually I want the result in another date field, but I choose text field instead as testing purposes because text field accept wide variety of result.

In below codes, the result will be `2012-06-30 10:05:00`:

```
// Extract the first field item
$date_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_date_start_rent');
$date_item = array_shift($date_items);
$integer_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_subscription_period');
$integer_item = array_shift($integer_items);

// Get the field value
$start_rent = $date_item['value'];
$period = $integer_item['value'];

// Update the other field
$node->field_cubagan[$node->language][0]['value'] = $start_rent;

// Save the node
node_save($node);
```

But under `Update the other field`, instead of get unmodified result from `$start_rent`, I want the result become: "Datetime" + "x years" which "Datetime" is from `field_date_start_rent` while the "x" of the years is taken from `field_subscription_period`

I'm not sure if strtotime only works on unix timestamp or only on `Y-m-d h:i:s` format or works on both.

both below codes giving same result `2012-06-30 10:05:00` because in second codes, it converted to unix timestamp, and then converted back to the time format:

```
$node->field_cubagan[$node->language][0]['value'] = $start_rent;
$node->field_cubagan[$node->language][0]['value'] = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($start_rent));
```

below codes will result in unix timestamp `1341050700`:

```
$node->field_cubagan[$node->language][0]['value'] = strtotime($start_rent);
```

But strange thing is, I always failed when trying to calculate.

In below 3 codes is example where I always get warning and not works (I'm using `+1 year` as testing purposes):

```
$node->field_cubagan[$node->language][0]['value'] = strtotime('+1 year',$start_rent);
$node->field_cubagan[$node->language][0]['value'] = strtotime('+1 year',date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($start_rent)));
$node->field_cubagan[$node->language][0]['value'] = strtotime('+1 year',"date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($start_rent))");
```

What actually I've missed and what is the right codes?

Answer (score 1):

I got it. It should be:

```
// Extract the first field item
$date_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_date_start_rent');
$date_item = array_shift($date_items);
$integer_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_subscription_period');
$integer_item = array_shift($integer_items);

// Get the field value
$start_rent = $date_item['value'];
$period = $integer_item['value'];

// Update the other field
$node->field_cubagan[$node->language][0]['value'] = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime("+$period year",strtotime($start_rent)));

// Save the node
node_save($node);
```